# Ruby on Rails - how to check column names in table (in the view) when inserting elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm beginner in Rails and I have the following problem:
I have one hash, and I am using keys from it as headers in the table (in the view).
So I have something like this:

```
<thead>
    <th>
        Team
    </th>
    <% @summary_hash.each do |k,v| %>
    <th>
        <%= k.name %>
    </th>
    <% end %>
</thead>
```

Let's say I have 3 kolumns (I am not counting column "Teams").

After that I have another hash with key-values pairs where key is always one of `k.name`  from the previous hash. The thing is there can be less than three key-value pairs. I need to iterate through this second hash and put value to my table in the proper column. It is simple when I have always 3 pairs and 3 columns. But if I have less than 3 pairs, I need to check somehow to which column my value should go. I need to compare column name and key from 2nd hash. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column are fixed,  so pull the value out of `another hash` if exists, or print out nothing

```
<thead>
    <th>
        Team
    </th>
    <% @summary_hash.each do |k,v| %>
    <th>
        <%= k.name %>
    </th>
    <% end %>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> Team one </td>
        <% @summary_hash.keys.each do |key| %>
            <td><%= @second_hash[key.name] %></td>
       <% end %>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```